# Can transaction fees for same-day trades be deducted from UK capital gains?

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, fees, capital-gain

Let's assume I buy and sell the same amount of shares on the same day and that the net result is zero, excluding transaction fees.

Can - or should - these fees be deducted from the capital gains tax?